# build a dynamic link in devexpress ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I try to build a dynamic link in devexpress [batch diting](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/BatchEditing). 
Well, i need to build link like:

```
<a href="/Terceiros/carregarTerceiroAlerta?idForn=@item.IdFornecedor&idFilialForn=@item.IdFilial" target = "_blank">Ir para ...
```

Where `@item.IdFornecedor` and `@item.IdFilial` are dynamic values by line.

Now, how i can build a column with this values?

```
settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.SetDataItemTemplateContent(a =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                   "<a href=''>asd</a>");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It possible using `DataBinder.Eval(a.DataItem, "IdForn")`

```
    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.SetDataItemTemplateContent(a =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                   "<a href='/Terceiros/carregarTerceiroAlerta?idForn=" + DataBinder.Eval(a.DataItem, "IdForn") + "&idFilialForn=" + DataBinder.Eval(a.DataItem, "IdFilialForn") + "'target = \"_blank\">Ir para ...</a>");
        });
        c.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(7);
    });
```